# How does one Ingest into Fedora Commons using PHP?

Tags: php, curl, fedora-commons

I'm trying to ingest a simple image file into Fedora Commons using PHP, but I can't make it work (Fedora Commons returns 500 when I try to attach a datastream to my new empty object).

I've posted my entire code at the end of this question, but here is some pseudo-code just to get the idea:

When the user selects a file on his computer and presses on the submit button, my script gets called and, ...

- Uploads the file into a temporary directory (I can see that image by visiting `http://localhost/drupal/sites/default/files/images/singe_6.jpg`)
- Creates a new empty Fedora Commons object (I can see that object by visiting `http://myFedoraServer:8082/fedora/objects/some%3Apid`)
- Attaches the file to the empty object as a datastream by using cURL to POST to the following URL: `http://myFedoraServer:8082/fedora/objects/some:pid/datastreams/myDatastreamID?controlGroup=M&dsLocation=http://localhost/drupal/sites/default/files/images/singe_6.jpg`
- Receives a 500 error response from the Fedora server, displays an error message and quits

**Other attempts**

- Changing the path to the file (`dsLocation`) to a relative path (`/sites/default/files/images/singe_6.jpg` instead of `http://localhost/drupal/sites/default/files/images/singe_6.jpg`). Changes nothing.
- Changing the path to the file (`dsLocation`) to an absolute path towards a random picture on the internet (`http://http://colibri45.c.o.pic.centerblog.net/cv369byr.jpg` instead of `http://localhost/drupal/sites/default/files/images/singe_6.jpg`) Changes nothing.

What am I doing wrong here? Are there any example scripts out there I could use as inspiration?

---

**The code**

Here is my code, which creates an *upload file* form in drupal and attempts to save that file to Fedora Commons:

```
<?php

// Create the form with drupal's form api
function fedora_test($form, $form_state) {
    $form = array(
        '#attributes' => array(
            'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data'
        ),
        'fichier' => array(
            '#tree' => false,
            '#type' => 'file'
        ),
        'enregistrer' => array(
            '#type' => 'submit',
            '#value' => t('Enregistrer'),
            '#submit' => array('fedora_test_enregistrer')
        )
    );

    return $form;
}

// Validate the form data before going on to the submission function (see fedora_test_enregistrer)
function fedora_test_validate($form, &$form_state) {
    $validators = array(
        "file_validate_extensions" => array(variable_get("allowed_extensions")),
        "file_validate_size" => array(variable_get("max_image_size"))
    );
    $file = file_save_upload('fichier', $validators, variable_get("uploaded_files_destination"));
    if ($file !== false && $file !== null) {
        $form_state['file_storage'] = $file;
    } else {
        form_set_error('fichier', "Impossible de charger le fichier");
    }
}

// Use cURL with the provided functions and return the result if the HTTP Code recieved matches the expected HTTP Code
function curlThis($curlOptions, $expectedHttpCode) {
    $returnValue = false;
    try {
        $curlHandle = curl_init();
        if ($curlHandle === false) {
            throw new Exception(
                "`curl_init()` returned `false`"
            );
        }
        $settingOptionsSucceeded = curl_setopt_array($curlHandle, $curlOptions);
        if ($settingOptionsSucceeded === false) {
            throw new Exception(
                sprintf(
                    "`curl_setopt_array(...)` returned false. Error: %s. Info: %s",
                    curl_error($curlHandle),
                    print_r(curl_getinfo($curlHandle), true)
                ),
                curl_errno($curlHandle)
            );
        }
        $curlReturn = curl_exec($curlHandle);
        if ($curlReturn === false) {
            throw new Exception(
                sprintf(
                    "`curl_exec(...)` returned false. Error: %s. Info: %s",
                    curl_error($curlHandle),
                    print_r(curl_getinfo($curlHandle), true)
                ),
                curl_errno($curlHandle)
            );
        }
        $httpCode = curl_getinfo($curlHandle, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
        if ($httpCode === false) {
            throw new Exception(
                sprintf(
                    "`curl_getinfo(...)` returned false. Error: %s.",
                    curl_error($curlHandle)
                ),
                curl_errno($curlHandle)
            );
        }
        if ($httpCode !== $expectedHttpCode) {
            throw new Exception(
                sprintf(
                    "`curl_getinfo(...)` returned an unexpected http code (expected %s, but got %s). Error: %s. Complete info: %s",
                    $expectedHttpCode,
                    $httpCode,
                    curl_error($curlHandle),
                    print_r(curl_getinfo($curlHandle), true)
                ),
                curl_errno($curlHandle)
            );
        }
        $returnValue = $curlReturn;
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        trigger_error(
            sprintf(
                "(%d) %s",
                $e->getCode(),
                $e->getMessage()
            ),
            E_USER_ERROR
        );
    }
    return $returnValue;
}

// Create a new empty object in Fedora Commons and return its pid
function createNewEmptyObject($prefix, $id) {
    $returnValue = false;

    // Build URL
    $protocol = variable_get("fedora_protocol");
    $host = variable_get("fedora_host");
    $port = variable_get("fedora_port");
    $context = variable_get("fedora_context");
    $pid = $prefix . ":" . $id;
    $url = sprintf(
        "%s://%s:%d/%s/objects/%s",
        $protocol,
        $host,
        $port,
        $context,
        $pid
    );

    // Build cURL options
    $userPassword = variable_get("fedora_username") . ":" . variable_get("fedora_password"); // username:password
    $verifyPeer = false; // false for ignoring self signed certificates
    $headers = array("Accept: text/xml", "Content-Type: text/xml");
    $curlOptions = array(
        CURLOPT_URL => $url,
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $headers,
        CURLOPT_USERPWD => $userPassword,
        CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH => CURLAUTH_BASIC,
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => $verifyPeer,
        CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_POST => true
    );

    // Try `cURL`ing
    $result = curlThis($curlOptions, 201);
    if ($result === $pid) {
        $returnValue = $result;
    }
    return $returnValue;
}

function attachDatastream ($pid, $file, $datastreamID) {

    $returnValue = false;

    // Build URL
    $protocol = variable_get("fedora_protocol");
    $host = variable_get("fedora_host");
    $port = variable_get("fedora_port");
    $context = variable_get("fedora_context");
    $url = sprintf(
        "%s://%s:%d/%s/objects/%s/datastreams/%s?controlGroup=M&dsLocation=%s",
        $protocol,
        $host,
        $port,
        $context,
        $pid,
        $datastreamID,
        file_create_url($file->uri)
    );

    drupal_set_message("url: " . $url, 'warning');

    // Build cURL options
    $userPassword = variable_get("fedora_username") . ":" . variable_get("fedora_password"); // username:password
    $verifyPeer = false; // false for ignoring self signed certificates
    $headers = array("Accept: text/xml", "Content-Type: text/xml");
    $curlOptions = array(
        CURLOPT_URL => $url,
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $headers,
        CURLOPT_USERPWD => $userPassword,
        CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH => CURLAUTH_BASIC,
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => $verifyPeer,
        CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_POST => true
    );

    // Try `cURL`ing
    $result = curlThis($curlOptions, 201);
    if ($result === $pid) {
        $returnValue = $result;
    }
    return $returnValue;
}

function fedora_test_enregistrer($form, &$form_state) {

    $pid = createNewEmptyObject("personne", "myObjectID");
    if ($pid) {
        drupal_set_message("Creating empty object succeeded. PID: " . $pid);
        $result = attachDatastream($pid, $form_state['file_storage'], "myDatastreamID");
        if ($result) {
            drupal_set_message("Attaching a datastream to pid " . $pid . " succeeded!");
        } else {
            form_set_error("FAILED ATTACHING DATASTREAM TO NEW OBJECT");
        }
    } else {
        form_set_error("FAILED CREATING NEW EMPTY OBJECT");
    }
}

?>
```

**The result**

> Creating empty object succeeded. PID: personne:myObjectID
>
> url:
>   http://vitdevelapp-cen.cen.umontreal.ca:8082/fedora/objects/personne:myObjectID/datastreams/myDatastreamID?controlGroup=M&dsLocation=http://localhost/drupal/sites/default/files/images/singe_6.jpg
>
> User error : (0) `curl_getinfo(...)` returned an unexpected http code
>   (expected 201, but got 500). Error: . Complete info: Array ( [url] =>
>   http://vitdevelapp-cen.cen.umontreal.ca:8082/fedora/objects/personne:myObjectID/datastreams/myDatastreamID?controlGroup=M&dsLocation=http://localhost/drupal/sites/default/files/images/singe_6.jpg
>   [content_type] => [http_code] => 500 [header_size] => 215
>   [request_size] => 330 [filetime] => -1 [ssl_verify_result] => 0
>   [redirect_count] => 0 [total_time] => 0.602249 [namelookup_time] =>
>   1.9E-5 [connect_time] => 0.005847 [pretransfer_time] => 0.005849 [size_upload] => 0 [size_download] => 0 [speed_download] => 0
>   [speed_upload] => 0 [download_content_length] => 0
>   [upload_content_length] => -1 [starttransfer_time] => 0.602222
>   [redirect_time] => 0 [certinfo] => Array ( ) ) dans curlThis() (ligne
>   100 dans
>   /var/www/drupal/sites/all/modules/editChercheur/fedora_test.php).

**from Fedora logs**

```
org.fcrepo.server.errors.GeneralException: Error getting http://localhost/drupal/sites/default/files/images/singe_6.jpg

Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connexion refusée
```

(`Connexion refusée` translates to `Connection refused`)

Comment: Could someone help me edit this question? I'm kind of new to the Fedora Commons world and I suspect some terminology might be slightly off...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What was the 500 error message text in the Fedora logs? Fedora can throw an error for a lot of stupid reasons, but without the error message text it is difficult to start debugging this problem.

My first guess is that perhaps the image "singe_6.jpg" might not exist or be accessible to the Fedora server. Is the path to the image on "localhost" the same as your Fedora server vitdevelapp-cen.cen.umontreal.ca?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand that last question. I'm testing my drupal module locally (localhost) whereas Fedora is hosted on another server (vitdevelapp-cen.cen.umontreal.ca).

Comment: I tried using an image already on the internet instead of my own uploaded image, but that didn't change anything. See my last edit.

Comment: The logs seem to indicate that fedora couldn't get my image because the connection was refused... Again, see my edit. I don't know what to do though because no matter which image I try to send, I always get that same error message.

Comment: That answers a few questions. First, change "localhost" in the URL to the actual IP address or name of the Drupal computer. Second, verify that you can actually download the file from the Fedora server using CURL or similar program:

curl "http://YourDrupalServerIPAddress/drupal/sites/default/files/images/singe_6.jpg" >test.jpg

If this fails then there are two likely causes: 1 - the file does not exist on the Drupal server (it probably does based on the error) or 2 - There may be a firewall in place that prevents the Fedora server from downloading the file.

Comment: Indeed, it seems the fedora server doesn't have access to the files on the drupal server, nor anywhere else on the internet for that matter. The solution seems to be passing the file itself along with the request. I'm having trouble with that approach too though, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15276157/how-can-i-ingest-an-image-into-fedora-commons-using-php

Comment: Unfortunately, that is not something you can do with the Fedora API directly unless you are working with internally managed XML content (DC data streams, for example). This was part of the reason I had to develop a SOAP-based API on top of the Fedora API that does any required data transfers first, then calls Fedora operations with a file URI containing a link to a local (to the Fedora server) file.

Getting back to your Fedora Server, what happens when you use CURL to download something like the Google logo?

Comment: `curl http://www.google.ca/images/srpr/logo4w.png` -> `curl: (7) Failed to connect to 2607:f8b0:400b:801::101f: Network is unreachable`

Comment: Using the code in my question, I tried providing (through dsLocation) Fedora with a path to an image stored locally (on the fedora server) and it just gave me a 500 error with no log message at all.

Comment: If you can't use even use CURL from the the Fedora Server to get the current Goggle logo then you have larger networking issues that need to be resolved before you continue. 

Is there a firewall on the Fedora server that needs to be adjusted?