# fedora commons ingest object via REST error

Tags: php, rest, fedora-commons

I recently set up FEDORA for a project I am working on to catalogue various
media. I want to be able to consume files (datastreams) via the FEDORA REST api. I managed to create a digital object via curl with no issues at all. I also managed to add an html page as a datastream to the digital object mentioned above with no problems as well.

However, adding a digital object with other content types/file types fails and throws an internal server error 500. On checking the logs, the following error appears:

```
[http-bio-8080-exec-18] (DatastreamResource) Error with uploaded://47 : XML was not well-formed. Invalid byte 1 of 1-byte UTF-8 sequence
```

The following is my code snippet of how I am ingesting the files:

```
$url = "http://localhost:8080/fedora/objects/changeme:5/datastreams/NEWDS8?controlGroup=X&dsLabel=LAZLO";
        $file = "namibia2015.pdf";
        // Build cURL options
        $userPassword = "fedoraAdmin:test123"; // username:password
        $verifyPeer = false; // false for ignoring self signed certificates
        $headers = array("Accept: text/xml", "Content-Type: " . mime_content_type($file));
        $fileContents = file_get_contents($file);
        $curlOptions = array(
            CURLOPT_URL => $url,
            CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $headers,
            CURLOPT_USERPWD => $userPassword,
            CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH => CURLAUTH_BASIC,
            CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => $verifyPeer,
            CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
            CURLOPT_POST => true,
            CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $fileContents
        );
$curlHandle = curl_init();
$success = curl_setopt_array($curlHandle, $curlOptions);
   throw new Exception(
                   sprintf(
                       "curl_setopt_array(...) failed. Error: %s. Info: %s",
                       curl_error($curlHandle),
                       print_r(curl_getinfo($curlHandle), true)
                   ),
                   curl_errno($curlHandle)
               );
           }
           $curlReturn = curl_exec($curlHandle);
$httpCode = curl_getinfo($curlHandle, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
```

I came across this post [How can I ingest an image into Fedora Commons using PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15276157/how-can-i-ingest-an-image-into-fedora-commons-using-php) tried the suggested method but still no luck.

What am I doing wrong? What am I missing? Why is it possible to add an html file datastream to the digital object but it fails when I try to 
add .jpeg, .pdf, .txt etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally fixed the error. The exception was being caused by the way I was structuring my URL parameters in my curl request. Using a URL with the following format:

```
$url = "http://localhost:8080/fedora/objects/changeme:5/datastreams/NEWDS8?controlGroup=X&dsLabel=LAZLO";
```

will throw the error. Instead, you have to build an http query of all the options you want attached to the POST request. I did that as follows:

```
$array = array();
$array['dsID'] = '5' ;
$array['controlGroup'] = 'M' ;
$array['altIDS'] = 'Other';
$array['versionable'] = true;
$array['dsLabel'] = 'The pic';
$array['logMessage'] = 'Example log message';

$link = "http://localhost:8080/fedora/objects/changeme:5/datastreams/newobject";
$params = http_build_query($array);
$url = $link.'?'.$params; //add the http query parameters to the url
```

Thereafter, I made my curl request as before and it will successfully create a data stream attached to the digital object.

Hope this will help someone in the future.